# fancybox iframe + jcrop problems on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, fancybox, jcrop

After I upload an image, I open it on an iframe with fancybox and use jcrop (thumbnail example http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail) to make some cut (this is a profile photo upload).

Everything works fine in all browsers except IE (oh serious? :/ )

Don´t know why but on IE the iframe appears locked. I can click on every link but can´t use mouse to make the selections, shows not-allowed icon on cursor.

Does anybody knows why IE has this action and, if possible, how to change this?
If it´s not possible I´ll use other solution with no iframes.

Comment: better show some code or a link to the page with the issue, otherwise we can spend days just guessing

Answer (score 0):

With a little more time I analysed this better and I saw that Jcrop was not loading on IE, just because the code that applies Jcrop in the image was running before Fancybox done generating the content of the iframe.

window.load and document.ready was not enought.
I had to use this code to make it work on IE.

```
$('#target').load(function () {
loadJcrop();
});
```

"#target" is the id of the image to be cropped, and loadJcrop() the function that applies Jcrop to it.